# Send text of a select by javascript to java class or servlet

Tags: javascript, java, php, jsp

I am trying to pass the selected variable or text from a SELECT - OPTION of a JSP to a java connection class or any class, ideally this variable is global so that it travels through all the classes used.

This is my JSP with the JavaScript part where I get the text of the selected thing.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowSelected()
{
    /* Para obtener el texto */
    var combo = document.getElementById("base");
    var selected  = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text = <%=VARIABLE.getBD() %>;
}
</script>
```

```html
 <select class="select100" name="cbobd"  id="base"  onchange="ShowSelected()">
     <option>--SELECCIONE--</option>
     <option>BASE1</option>
     <option>BASE2</option>
 </select>
```

It should be noted that this variable is obtained from the connections class where the get and set constructors are.

```
public class conexiones {
public String BD;

public String getBD() {
    return BD;
}

public void setBD(String BD) {
    this.BD = BD;
}
```

every time I select in the select it replaces it with the text "NULL",
This logic is the ideal one or in case there would be another one, you can correct me, thank you